# Why is this simple ant file being marked as an error in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have a very, very simple any build script:

```
<project name="quiz_jar" default="all">
<target name="all">
<jar destfile="/home/mike/export/quiz_all.jar" duplicate="preserve">
    <archives>
        <zips>
            <files includes="/home/mike/export/quiz.jar" />
            <files includes="/home/mike/download/jeuclid-3.1.9/repo/*.jar" />
        </zips>
    </archives>
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.antlersoft.quiz.ui.QuizFrame"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
</target>
</project>
```

It works fine when I run it as an Ant task in Eclipse (or from the command line)

However, in the Problems tab, it is marked with the following error:

> Default target all does not exist in this
>   project

Comment: Not because there is no </project> at the end-- that was in the question but only shows on the editing page, not when the question is viewed (that'd be a stackexchange bug...)  I added some more spaces  and now the closing </project> shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I change any character in the file (like in a path), the error flag goes away.  I added a comment to make the error go away.  Would still like to know what the problem was.

Comment: If you change it back again does the error return? Are you by any change running out of disk space or quota? It's a shot in the dark, but when I have seen similar apparently inexplicable errors in Eclipse it has often been due to the user filling their disk quota, so Eclipse cannot successfully save the file, and unfortunately does not produce a helpful error message.

Comment: @Ben - If I change it back the error comes back.  I made the error go away with the comment, re-started Eclipse (which I should've done before) and when Eclipse re-started there was no error.  Then I removed the comment, and the error came back!!  It looks like it is not a reproducible problem with other people's installations, though.

Answer (score 0):

The closing tag `</project>` is missing. After adding it I get no errors or warnings in eclipse.

Comment: sorry -- the </project> is in the file and was in the submitted question but did not show up in the question until I added some spaces in front of it.  That's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are not closing with a `</project>` tag, so Eclipse might not be seeing the `<target>`.

When I ran this from the command line I got a more informative message:

> XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

Comment: sorry -- the </project> is in the file and was in the submitted question but did not show up in the question until I added some spaces in front of it.  That's not the problem.

Comment: After I added `</project>`, the command line error message said `jar doesn't support the nested "archives" element.`. Looking at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html, I see that `manifest` will work, but `archives` will not. BTW, I have always found it helpful to put -debug -verbose on the Eclipse argument when debugging ant scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue for myself by updating Maven. Right click on the project->Maven->Update Project.